# Why is VisualState.StateTriggers not recognized or is not accessible?

Tags: uwp

I am trying to change to BorderBrush of a Button based on an event.

I tried searching how to change visual states but all of the them use a combination of both VisualState.StateTriggers and VisualState.Setters. When I use them in my Style, I get error message "The member 'Setters' is not recognized or is not accessible".

Development Environment

- Windows 10 Professional
- Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 Update 4
- .Net Framework 4.6.1

  ```
  <Style x:Key="ButtonGameLarge" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                  <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                      <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                          <VisualStateGroup >
                              <VisualState x:Name="whateverName">
                                  <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                      <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                                  </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                  <VisualState.Setters>
                                      <Setter Target="RootGrid.Height" Value="80" />
                                      <Setter Target="RootGrid.Width" Value="400" />
                                      <Setter Target="RootGrid.Margin" Value="0,0,0,20" />
                                  </VisualState.Setters>
                              </VisualState>
                          </VisualStateGroup>
                      </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                  </Grid>
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
  ```

Comment: Have you tried actually compiling it? Visual Studio seems to sometimes have issues with thinking that XAML is invalid, but it still compiles fine.

Comment: It doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you're using Visual Studio 2013. However, according to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx), you need at least Visual Studio 2015 to develop for UWP. My guess is that the "Universal" you selected is the old Windows 8.1-style "universal" which doesn't have the `VisualState` capabilities of UWP. You're not really working with a UWP project at all.

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty project in Visual Studio, pasted in your XAML code into my main page and applied the style to a button. It compiles and runs fine.

Are you sure your project is a *Universal Windows* project and not something older (like *Windows Runtime* which does not have `StateTriggers` if I recall)? I'll need more information.

Comment: Yes. I started the project by selecting "Blank App(Universal Apps)".